# Git error message changed over the years - should the most popular question be updated?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, specific-question

I noticed that with 2k+ rep my edits are no longer reviewed and are automatically applied.  I'd like to edit this question:

- [Git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945654/git-checkout-on-a-remote-branch-does-not-work)

I would like to add an update at the bottom that notes that this error is now stated by git as

> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'branch-name' at the same time.
>   Did you intend to checkout 'origin/branch-name' which can not be resolved as commit?

But I'm not sure if that would be accepted by the community (and I'd like to also confirm whether or not I'm even correct). This would help eliminate duplicates such as this question:

- ["Cannot update paths and switch to branch at the same time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984262/cannot-update-paths-and-switch-to-branch-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Making edits should mean you are entirely comfortable that it is allowed. Inquiring whether some edit would be acceptable should be done through a meta post (as you do now).

Comment: You can make a new question since it's a possibly interesting discussion but I can tell you right now that editing that question to indicate a newer error message should be done by providing credible sources that indicate the error message has changed and is appropriate for that exact scenario.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel This would also only be OK if the new error message replaces the old one in exactly the same circumstances. I'd also add that the new error message should not replace, but be added next to the old one in the question, since some users might still be using an older version.